# My website stops in IIS 8 when i install self signed certificate

Tags: iis, ssl, https, iis-express

I referred to [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYwOMuBDhPU) tutorial and made a self-signed certificate and used https to my default site. But when i bind https my website stops [*image below*]

[image]

and when i try starting it, it shows

[image]

and when i browse to `http://localhost` then it opens the iis8 but when i try to open `https://localhost` then it says

```
**The connection has timed out**

The server at localhost is taking too long to respond.
```

Answer (score 9):

Just thought I'd add to this. You can stop Skype from running on port 80/443 so no need to close it.

Tools > Options > Advanced > Connection
- Uncheck "Use port 80 and 433 as alternatives for incoming messages"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother you guys. It was a silly mistake of mine. The port assigned was being used by the skype so it happen. I terminated the skype from the task manager and it worked fine... Sorry to bother you guys